# Alarm not firing in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager

my alarm is not firing at all.

MainActivity:

```
    final Context context = this;

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);

    Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmReceiver.class);
    PendingIntent alarmIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);

    AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarmMgr.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, calendar.getTimeInMillis(),AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, alarmIntent);
```

AlarmReceiver:

```
public class AlarmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static String NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification-id";
    public static String NOTIFICATION = "notification";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)context.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

        Notification notification = intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);
        int id = intent.getIntExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0);
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification);

    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/>

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Using:
compileSdkVersion 25 minSdkVersion 23 targetSdkVersion 25

Comment: have you added the receiver in manifest ?

Comment: what does this return? `intent.getParcelableExtra(NOTIFICATION);`

Comment: Okay then how you are sure about Alarm is not firing because it is not generating notification ??

Comment: I also have Log in onReceive before the notifications, cant see it either.

Comment: First, `Calendar.getInstance()` already create a `Date` with the system time (no need to `setTimeInMillis`). Then, if you test this after 13:30, you will miss it ;) it is in the past (nevermind, didn't see the repeat call)

Comment: Each time I run it I set the time 2 min forward and just wait. This is the most frustrating debugging I had. Supposedly the time now 14:05. I set it to 14:07 and wait....

Comment: Note : `Calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 30)` is a good trick to only wait 30 seconds ;). Have you add every permission needed ?

Comment: What permission do I need for alarm?

Comment: `<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>`

Comment: Give me 2 mins to test it.... :)

Comment: I would say `SET_ALARM` and maybe `WAKE_LOCK` for the Alarm RTC_WAKEUP

Comment: Added: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_ALARM"/> and still nothing happens

Comment: Adding manifest to question....

Comment: Are you sure you can access `<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" />`. You should try using `adb shell` to check if the intent is received.

Comment: Every time you are using the same `calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 13);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 30);` ?

Comment: @DarshanSoni, read the previous comment, he said he was setting it each time to 2minute in the futur for the tests

Comment: ohh sorry , finally he found the ans :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For API 23 and above you can use  setAndAllowWhileIdle():

So change your code to:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 23)
        alarmManager. setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent); 
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 19)
    alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 16)
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, targetCal.getTimeInMillis(), 1 * 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, pendingIntent);
```

and check if is it working or not.

Comment: I will check it, but the phone not in idle state when testing

Comment: Oh my god!!! That actually solved it.... But I cant understand why. This should worked when without the idle state.
Thanx @AxelH for your help!